# Contract import from GitHub gives an error "Unable to import "undefined": TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler, import

This would be an old issue, but the solutions I have seen on this site aren't working. I'm trying to import a contract of OpenZeppelin to my Remix IDE.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/drafts/Counters.sol";
```

And it gives me an error:

> Unable to import "undefined": TypeError: Failed to fetch

[image]

Comment: I believe that you need to change this:

Comment: `https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob`

Comment: To this: `openzeppelin-contracts/tree`

Comment: For sure you need to get rid of the `https://github.com/` prefix.

Comment: @goodvibration: I'm sorry, not in that sense :) just need to know that you are suggesting in this way? `import "openzeppelin-contracts/tree/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. If it doesn't work, then try to add back the prefix `OpenZeppelin/`.

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration, Tried both the ways, it's showing file not found.

Answer (score 1):

To import from a tag or branch use `/blob/<tag>`

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

It is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html but it works.

Comment: Thanks! the issue is weird, it is working fine as shown in the question, previously it was showing an error.